# Shell: how to right justify columns for my file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, printf

I have a data file like below:

```
Jones,Bill,235 S. Williams St.,Denver,CO,80221,(303) 244-7989
Smith,Tom,404 Polk Ave.,Los Angeles,CA,90003,(213) 879-5612
```

I want each line be separated by ',' and right justify columns, just like below

```
Jones    Bill    235 S. Williams St.        Denver    CO     80221       (303) 244-7989
Smith     Tom          404 Polk Ave.   Los Angeles    CA     90003       (213) 879-5612
```

This is my code and it doesn't work. Pls help, thx.

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line" | awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%15s" $i}'
  echo
done < "datafile.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pipe each line to awk with a loop. Loops are slow and it decreases readability (have a look at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765)). Awk reads lines by default, just provide the filename as an argument:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%22s",$i};print ""}' datafile.txt
```

Notice `%15s` would not be enough to yield a nice table, so I increased it to `%22s`. And you missed the comma `,` in printf statement, that is why it your attempt failed.

You could also use `column -ts "," datafile.txt`, but that would left justify the output.

Answer (score 1):

Awk itself has `for` loop. Using a shell `for` loop can work too.

```
$ cat file
Jones,Bill,235 S. Williams St.,Denver,CO,80221,(303) 244-7989
Smith,Tom,404 Polk Ave.,Los Angeles,CA,90003,(213) 879-5612
$ awk -F, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%20s", $i); printf "\n"; }' file
               Jones                Bill 235 S. Williams St.              Denver                  CO               80221      (303) 244-7989
               Smith                 Tom       404 Polk Ave.         Los Angeles                  CA               90003      (213) 879-5612
$ 
$ while read line; do echo "$line" | awk -F, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%20s", $i); printf "\n"; }'; done < file 
               Jones                Bill 235 S. Williams St.              Denver                  CO               80221      (303) 244-7989
               Smith                 Tom       404 Polk Ave.         Los Angeles                  CA               90003      (213) 879-5612
$
```

Comment: Don't use the shell loop, See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 0):

With `column` and `rev`:

```
$ rev file | column -ts, | rev
Jones  Bill  235 S. Williams St.       Denver  CO  80221  (303) 244-7989
Smith   Tom        404 Polk Ave.  Los Angeles  CA  90003  (213) 879-5612
```

or with GNU `column` (for `-R`) and `seq`:

```
$ column -ts, -R $(seq -s, 999) file
Jones  Bill  235 S. Williams St.       Denver  CO  80221  (303) 244-7989
Smith   Tom        404 Polk Ave.  Los Angeles  CA  90003  (213) 879-5612
```